# Update the duplicate row with the previous value MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to update the duplicates value in the level_number to the maximum value of the previous row

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select
    t.*,
    case when count(*) over(partition by id, level order by day) > 1
        then max(level) over(order by day, level rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
        else level
    end new_level
from mytable t
```

Comment: I modified the query and it worked 
`select 
    t.*, 
    case when count(*) over(partition by id, day order by day) > 1 
        then max(level) over(order by day, ID rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) 
        else level 
    end new_level 
from mytable t`

However, I have different IDs. How could I run the query for each group of ID?